# How to fill a textbox in a webpage to show the result as clickable link

Tags: javascript, php, html

as a user not (Developer)

in a shop website (haraj.com.sa), when i fill textbox with Url, The result will give the url as text (not clickable)

which code can help to put it in text box to show the result as clickable link

Comment: You might want to add a click event in that textbox and handle the redirect to the URL in the textbox in that event

Comment: What have you tried ? Where is your code ? Have you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event to your TextBox, so it redirects to the page you want it to. Otherwise just add the URL to a hyperlink

```js
function redirect(){
  var redirectionUrl = $('#tbUrl')[0].value;
  window.location.href = redirectionUrl;
}
```

```css
.clickable{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tbUrl" type="text" class="clickable" value="https://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="redirect()">
```